# Regex fails every second call

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a regex check which fails every second time that it is called.

```
const PHONE_REGEX = /^(0{0,2}|\+|[1-9])[1-9]\d{7,}$/g;
const validatePhoneNumber = (telNumber) => PHONE_REGEX.test(telNumber);

const input = "01695233966";

[ validatePhoneNumber(input), validatePhoneNumber(input), validatePhoneNumber(input), validatePhoneNumber(input) ]
```

I have tried replacing `validatePhoneNumber` calls with just `PHONE_REGEX.test` but I still experience the same issue.

Comment: I wonder how can we stop the flood of these questions. But even logically thinking, why anyone needs to match a whole string more than one time? Why add `g` modifier at all when you use `^` and `$` anchors?

Comment: Thanks for the close @WiktorStribiżew, it has solved my problem. I did attempt to search but did not find the question about the global flag.